# Moving Aggregations ElasticSearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

G'day all i've been trying to crack away at getting a moving aggregation up and running for my application.

Below is an example of what my document looks like for the metrics.

```
"_index" : "metrics-2017-06-23",
"_type" : "metric",
 "_id" : "AVzUTWSCHd9DG10LCpmo",
"_score" : 0.0,
    "_source" : {
  "organisation" : "Organisation",
  "deployments" : [
    {
      "deployment_name" : "tqwerty",
      "instances" : [
        {
          "instance_name" : "7962c130ae1247229ee67aa534172f77",
          "object" : "fff",
          "version" : "adacb76ebd21",
          "cpu" : [
            {
              "time" : 1498174600,
              "value" : 10000
            }
          ],
          "disk_read" : [
            {
              "time" : 1498174600,
              "value" : 430
            }
          ],
          "disk_write" : [
            {
              "time" : 1498174600,
              "value" : 0
            }
          ],
          "net_read" : [
            {
              "time" : 1498174600,
              "value" : 0
            }
          ],
          "net_write" : [
            {
              "time" : 1498174600,
              "value" : 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}
]
```

Ive got the Curl request down to where it works and Isolates the deployments I want. But its just not showing my moving agg. I'm not to sure why as Im following word for word on the documentation.

```
curl -XPOST '10.0.0.34:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"size": 20,
"query": { 
  "bool": { 
   "must": [
  { "match": { "organisation":   "Organisation"        }},
 { "match":  { "deployments.deployment_name": "tqwerty" }}
   ]
}
},
    "aggs": {
    "my_date_histo":{                
    "date_histogram":{
        "field":"deployments.instances.cpu.time",
        "interval":"30s"
       },
        "aggs":{
            "the_sum":{
            "sum":{ "field": "deployments.instances.cpu.value" } 
            },
            "the_movavg":{
            "moving_avg":{ "buckets_path": "the_sum" } 
        }
    }
}
}
}
 '
```

Curl request runs fine but doesn't show the moving agg does show the sum though and it matches with the data fine.

Thanks,

Comment: query looks good ,try adding other parameters like window,model as shown here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html

Comment: also try size:0 to fetch all data,may be size:20 is the reason .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I said from the comments -

```
 curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
     {
       "size": 0,
       "query": { 
              "bool": { 
                   "must": [
                         { "match": { "organisation":   "Organisation"}},
                         { "match":  { "deployments.deployment_name": "tqwerty" }}
                   ]
                  }
               },
       "aggs": {
                "my_date_histo":{                
                   "date_histogram":{
                      "field":"deployments.instances.cpu.time",
                      "interval":"30s"
              },
                 "aggs":{
                 "the_sum":{
                 "sum":{ "field": "deployments.instances.cpu.value" } 
                },
                 "the_movavg":{
                      "moving_avg":{ "buckets_path": "the_sum" } 
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

**Conclusion**:Changing size to 0

Answer (score 1):

That seem to resolve my issues. Which is surprising because it didn't the other day... If anyone else runs into this try what Tom said and hopefully it'll work for you.

Comment: glad to know that , please accept and upvote my answer , thanks